# Pushing messages in kafka to separate partitions by a key

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, kafka-python

I have a Kafka topic (**test-topic**) with 3 partitions, and a set of messages which contain a key that can take only 3 types of values, I want these messages to go to separate partitions based on their value.

```
from kafka import KafkaProducer
from kafka.partitioner import DefaultPartitioner

messages = [{"partition_key":"k1", "x":1},
            {"partition_key":"k2", "x":2},
            {"partition_key":"k3", "x":3},
            {"partition_key":"k1", "x":4},
            {"partition_key":"k2", "x":5}]

partitioner = DefaultPartitioner()
all_partitions = list(range(100))
available = all_partitions
dataPartitioner = partitioner(b'partition_key', all_partitions, available)

producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers="localhost:9092", value_serializer=lambda v: json.dumps(v).encode('utf-8'), partitioner = dataPartitioner)

for m in messages:
  producer.send('test-topic', m)
producer.flush()
```

In the above code, I want messages whose **partition_key** value is the same to go to the same partition.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write your custom implementation of the [`Partitioner`](https://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/Partitioner.html) interface, and give that class to the `KafkaProducer` at the time of initialisation.

E.g.,

```
 private static Properties createProducerConfig(String brokers) {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("bootstrap.servers", brokers);
    //more properties
    props.put("partitioner.class","com.app.KafkaUserCustomPatitioner");
    return props;
    }
```